# multiple javascript problems

Tags: javascript, html, responsive-design, sticky

I have a responsive navigation and a sticky content section on several pages. They both work fairly flawlessly by themselves but when I put them on the same page the sticky elements get really glitchy.

http://michaelcullenbenson.com/kaeding.html

There is the content on the left that is the pictures, which works normally, but the text on the right side of it is suppose to stick to the top of the page on scroll and detach when you reach the section below that one. I may just have to combine all the javascripts into one but I'm pretty lost on how to do that properly.

I used this for the sticky function

http://viget.com/inspire/jquery-stick-em

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: The responsive navigation is made up of 4 different scripts. and the sticky elements are two scripts. I figured the best way to show everything was to just include the link to the site. Since I'm not really sure it would be efficient to post all that in here. The names of the scripts for the responsive navigation are:

fastclick.js, scroll.js, fixed-responsive-nav.js, and responsive-nav.js

The scripts for the sticky elements are jquery.js, and jquery.stickem.js

should I post all those scripts on here? I thought inspect element would make more sense.